# Creating a large Series from two MultiIndex DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a DataFrame lets say df1 with multi index, e.g.

`index1 = MultiIndex.from_tuples([('1','c'),('1','d'),('2','c'),('2','d')], names = ['level1','level2'])`

and another DataFrame, lets say df2 with multi index, e.g.
`index2 =  MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1,'1','c'), (2,'1','c'),(3,'1','d'),(4,'2','d'),(6,'2','d')],names = ['level0','level1','level2'])`

What I want to do is create a pd.Series object that has the indices of 'level0' (they are all unique), based on the levels 'level1', 'level2' from certain column from df1. So for example if
`df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['foo','bar','baz','qux'],'B':[['foo1','bar1','baz1','qux1']]}, index = index1)` 
I want to the input to be df1, df2 (only the index of this DataFrame matters not its contents), column name, e.g. if I take df1, with column name 'B' and index index2 the outcome should be
`pd.Series('foo1','foo1', 'bar1', 'qux1','qux1', index = [1,2,3,4,6])`

I wrote a quick code that works

```
result = [df1[column_name].loc[indx[1:]][0] for indx in df2.index] 
new_indx = [i[0] for i in df2.index]
result = pd.Series(result, index = new_index)
```

However, this is extremely slow as my second DataFrame is huge, I would like to a have solution, where I dont need to cycle through anything related to df2 (e.g. through df2.index) without pandas. Regular python cycles through df1 are OK as this DataFrame is much smaller.

Comment: too many typo in your example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example Code**

too many typo in your example code

```
import pandas as pd
index1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('1','c'),('1','d'),('2','c'),('2','d')], names=['level1','level2'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['foo','bar','baz','qux'],' B':['foo1','bar1','baz1','qux1']}, index=index1)
index2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1,'1','c'), (2,'1','c'),(3,'1','d'),(4,'2','d'),(6,'2','d')], names = ['level0','level1','level2'])
```

`df1`

```
                A   B
level1  level2      
1       c       foo foo1
        d       bar bar1
2       c       baz baz1
        d       qux qux1
```

`index2`(index of df2):

```
MultiIndex([(1, '1', 'c'),
            (2, '1', 'c'),
            (3, '1', 'd'),
            (4, '2', 'd'),
            (6, '2', 'd')],
           names=['level0', 'level1', 'level2'])
```

**Code**

```
index2.to_frame().join(df1).droplevel([0, 1])['B']
```

output:

```
level0
1    foo1
2    foo1
3    bar1
4    qux1
6    qux1
Name: B, dtype: object
```

To remove the name of index named level0, add `.rename_axis('')` at the end of the code.

Instead of `.droplevel([0, 1])`, you can also use `.droplevel(df1.index.names)`.